# Can't type double digits in select options without odd error

Tags: html, forms

I've been looking for an answer to this question and I've tried even figuring out the pattern myself but nothing really comes to mind. So here's the issue...

Say you have a select list of:

```
<select name='select'>
    <option value='01'>01</option>
    <option value='02'>02</option>
    <option value='03'>03</option>
    <option value='04'>04</option>
    <option value='05'>05</option>
    <option value='06'>06</option>
    .
    .
    .
    <option value='40'>40</option>
</select>
```

So in general you can just type the number on a ten key or the home keys and it will give you the number in the select list, like `01` will go to `01` and `10` will go to `10`, but when I type `22` it givens my `21`, or `33` will give me `32`.

It's not anything that is really breaking something but it's just kind of an odd situation, and for general knowledge purpose and because my boss and I have been pondering it for 24 hours, we just kind of want an answer as to why this is, and why when we type `11` it gives `11`.

Hopefully the question is not too abstract, but I thank you for any answers you can provide! It just seems like an interesting thing to ask about to me.

Comment: Isn't it a browser-specific feature?

Comment: see that's what we aren't sure about, we can't find any information on this.

Comment: Sometimes the key presses appear to be jumping based on index, instead of what's typed. But i'm unable to reproduce it with 33 and 22 http://jsfiddle.net/n6owLbjc/

Comment: Would it have something to do with the fact that the select list Is generated with PHP?

Comment: Nope. It's just how the browser is behaving

Comment: When I've selected an option with the mouse, and then press 22 it will navigate to `20` and then to `21`. If I wait a little longer, I can press 3 and it will navigate to `30` and 3 again it will go to `31`... weird.

Comment: This keyboard behavior makes more sense when the items in your list are words, instead of numbers. Maybe just a textbox[type=number] would be a better input element for this?

Comment: Well it doesn't have any real effect on the input process just some people picked this one odd item be like, "this is a slightly minor inconvenience" ha

Comment: in ie it would seem it is trying to work out what you want. Repeatedly pressing 2 for me is cycling through the 20s however if I type 33 it goes to 33. If I then start repeating 3 it begins to cycle through the 30s, first moving to 34 then 35...

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to wonder if it is browser specific, it's just odd